# Heap implementation of Djikstra's Shortest-path algorithm, C++

Tags: c++, algorithm

*EDIT: The code below works perfectly, the problem was in my implementation of the heap. Feel free to have a look if you're looking for a C++ implementation of the heap-based version of Djikstra's shortest path algorithm.*

I've spent the last few hours trying to debug my implementation of Djikstra's shortest path algorithm (the O(m*log(n) version that uses a heap), but am still running into bugs in a very small segment of my test cases. The test case I'm having trouble with is fairly large (there are 200 nodes in the graph), and so I don't know how useful it would be to include it here. Suffice to say, my implementation seems to generate the correct shortest path for all but a couple of the nodes.

For any algorithm experts out there, would you please have a look at what I've got and tell me where I've gone wrong?

```
#include "Heap.h"
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

void ReadFile(std::vector<Edge> adjList[], std::string fileName);
const int NUM_VERTICES = 200;
const int START_VERTEX = 29;

int main(){
    //valid entries in adjList start from[1] so that vertex #1 is stored in [1].
    std::vector<Edge> adjList[NUM_VERTICES + 1];
    std::vector<int> shortestPaths(NUM_VERTICES + 1);

    ReadFile(adjList, "dijkstraData.txt");
    //ReadFile(adjList, "test.txt");
    Heap heap(NUM_VERTICES);
    heap.InitializeForDjikstras(); 

    HeapEntry min(0, 0);

    //for each of the remaining vertices, process using Djikstra's greedy selection rule
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_VERTICES; i++){
        shortestPaths[min.id] = min.key;

        //recalculate keys of any nodes that now have edges crossing the boundary between X(processed) and V-X(unprocessed)
        for (int q = 0; q < adjList[min.id].size(); q++){
            int headID = adjList[min.id][q].id;
            int costToHead = adjList[min.id][q].cost;
            HeapEntry head = heap.Delete(headID);

            if (head.key > shortestPaths[min.id] + costToHead) {
                head.key = shortestPaths[min.id] + costToHead;
            }
            heap.Insert(head);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If it would help to see my implementation of a heap or the complete ReadFile implementation just let me know and I'll post it. I'm pretty sure they're working correctly though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was actually in my heap implementation. The code above is correct, so anyone looking for a heap implementation of Djikstra's algorithm feel free to have a look.

Comment: After reading the question, my guess was that a segfault was occurring somewhere in your Heap implementation ... For the next time : heavily use debugging tools (debugger, memory analysis ...)